# txt file with integers, strings and bulleted list (1.)

Tags: java, file, io, txt

I have a txt file which has several rows like this

```
7. SSWAB        38    15   -  57
```

but I don't need all the values, just the String and the integers.
I would use `nextInt` for the Integers, but how can I deal with 1. and -?

Also there is the string, what is a useful `nextString`? Is `next` enough?

I have tried something like this, just using tokens, but nothing happens

```
scanner.next(); //7.
String  s = (scanner.next()); //SAVES sswab
Integer n1 = scanner.nextInt(); //38
Integer n2 = scanner.nextInt(); //15
Integer n3 = scanner.nextInt(); //- is skipped, as next int is 57
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scanner.next(Pattern pattern)` for matching these groups.

Try this regex

```
-?\d+\.?(\d+)?|\w+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GUxgpr/1) 
It would catch all groups you mentioned plus fractional numbers and negative numbers.

Then you can use this regex in scanner

```
String text = "7. SSWAB        38    15   -  57    ";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    if(scanner.hasNext("-?\\d+\\.?(\\d+)?|\\w+")) {
        System.out.println(scanner.next("-?\\d+\\.?(\\d+)?|\\w+"));
    } else {
        scanner.next();
    }
}
```

This code catch all matching groups and skip others. 
 Output

```
7.
SSWAB
38
15
57
```